# DevExpress GridControl Does not Update properly even I set up the NotifyPropertyChanged event correctly

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I met a very strange Problem.

The basic idea is that I have a class to save data received from a trading api about forex price. Each property has been set with NotifyPropertyChanged method like below.

```
class RealTimeBar
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const double EPSILON = 0.0000001;

    private int _id;
    private string _symbol;
    private int _time;
    private float _open;
    private float _high;
    private float _low;
    private float _close;
    int _volume;

    public RealTimeBar(int id, string symbol)
    {
        _id = id;
        _symbol = symbol;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public string Symbol
    {
        get
        {
            return _symbol;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _symbol)
            {
                _symbol = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Symbol");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Time
    {
        get
        {
            return _time;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _time)
            {
                _time = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
        }
    }

    public float Open
    {
        get
        {
            return _open;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _open)
            {
                _open = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Open");
            }
        }
    }

    public float High
    {
        get
        {
            return _high;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _high)
            {
                _high = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("High");
            }
        }
    }

    public float Low
    {
        get
        {
            return _low;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _low)
            {
                _low = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Low");
            }
        }
    }

    public float Close
    {
        get
        {
            return _close;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _close)
            {
                _close = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Close");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return _volume;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _volume)
            {
                _volume = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Volume");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

It is quote a long class but with simple structure as you can see. Now I connected to api which fire event to me and I handle it by set the value from api to the class i defined.

```
    BindingList<RealTimeBar> _realTimeBarList = new BindingList<RealTimeBar>();
    public Hashtable _iForexHashtable = new Hashtable();

    private void _UpdateForexQuote(int tickerId, int time, double open, double high, double         low,    double close, int volume,
                             double wap, int count)
    {
        ///MessageBox.Show(tickerId.ToString());
        ((RealTimeBar)_iForexHashtable[tickerId]).Open = (float)open;
        ((RealTimeBar)_iForexHashtable[tickerId]).High = (float)high;
        ((RealTimeBar)_iForexHashtable[tickerId]).Low = (float)low;
        ((RealTimeBar)_iForexHashtable[tickerId]).Close = (float)close;
        ((RealTimeBar)_iForexHashtable[tickerId]).Volume = volume;

    }
```

After some setting up, the method _UpdateForexQuote would distribute the coming info into properties of RealTimeBar class. Everything is fine.

When I start the program, it does not update. I thought that there is no data coming in. But when I randomly click somewhere in the A1cell of gridcontrol, then click another B1cell, the previous A1cell would update. Then if i click C1cell, then the B1cell would update. If you do not click one cell , it would never update. I show you the picture:

[image]

As you can see, that after clicking first three lines, the first three lines showed delayed data and since I never touch the fourth line, it shows zero. And the condition is that I just clicked the fifth line Low cell, that is why the Low does not update but other cells updated. It is very strange. I use same code before under devexpress 11 with vs 2010. But now with devexpress 12 with vs 2012, I met this problem which never occurred before.

**UPDATE:**

Below is the method I use to 1. define bindinglist and a hashtable, 2. put objects into the hashtable first and add the object from hashtable to bindinglist 3. bind the bindinglist to gridcontrol.

```
private void earningButtonItem_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        _iTimer.AutoReset = false;
        _iTimer.Enabled = false;
        switchStockPool = "Earning Stock";
        disconnectButtonItem.PerformClick();
        connectButtonItem.PerformClick();
        _iheitanshaoEarningDBConnect = new DBConnect("heitanshaoearning");
        List<string>[] tempList;
        int tempHash;
        tempList = _iheitanshaoEarningDBConnect.SelectSymbolHighLow();
        _quoteEarningOnGridList.Clear();

        ///tempList[0].Count
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList[0].Count; i++)
        {
            tempHash = Convert.ToInt32(tempList[0][i].ToString().GetHashCode());
            _iStockEarningHistHashtable[tempHash] = new QuoteOnGridHist(tempList[0][i], (float)Convert.ToSingle(tempList[1][i]), (float)Convert.ToSingle(tempList[2][i]), (float)Convert.ToSingle(tempList[3][i]));
            _iStockEarningHashtable[tempHash] = new QuoteOnGrid(tempList[0][i], 0, 0);
            _quoteEarningOnGridList.Add((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockEarningHashtable[tempHash]);
            reqMktDataExStock(tempHash, tempList[0][i].ToString());
        }

        List<string>[] tempVolumeList;
        tempVolumeList = _iheitanshaoEarningDBConnect.SelectAverageVolume();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList[0].Count; i++)
        {
            tempHash = Convert.ToInt32(tempVolumeList[0][i].ToString().GetHashCode());
            ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockEarningHashtable[tempHash]).Average_Volume = ((float)Convert.ToSingle(tempVolumeList[1][i])) / volumeDenominator;
        }

        gridControl.DataSource = _quoteEarningOnGridList;
    }
    /////////////////////
```

Now when the price update event comes, the method below will update the object properties in hashtable. Since I defined Notifypropertychanged in object, it should update the object in bingdinglist and gridcontrol.

```
  private void _UpdateStockMarketQuote(int tikcerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute)
    {
        ////MessageBox.Show(tikcerId.ToString() + field.ToString() + price.ToString());
        if (switchStockPool == "Selected Stock")
        {
            if (field == 4)
            {
                ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockHashtable[tikcerId]).Gap_From_High = ((float)price - ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).High) / ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Close;
                ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockHashtable[tikcerId]).Gap_From_Low = ((float)price - ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Low) / ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Close;
                ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockHashtable[tikcerId]).Last_Price = (float)price;
            }
            //else if (field == 1)
            //{
            //    ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockHashtable[tikcerId]).Gap_From_High = ((float)price - ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).High) / ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Close;
            //    ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockHashtable[tikcerId]).Gap_From_Low = ((float)price - ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Low) / ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Close;
            //}
        }
        else if (switchStockPool == "Earning Stock")
        {
            if (field == 4)
            {
                ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockEarningHashtable[tikcerId]).Gap_From_High = ((float)price - ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockEarningHistHashtable[tikcerId]).High) / ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockEarningHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Close;
                ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockEarningHashtable[tikcerId]).Gap_From_Low = ((float)price - ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockEarningHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Low) / ((QuoteOnGridHist)_iStockEarningHistHashtable[tikcerId]).Close;
                ((QuoteOnGrid)_iStockEarningHashtable[tikcerId]).Last_Price = (float)price;

            }
            //else if (field == 1)
            //{
            //    ((quoteongrid)_istockearninghashtable[tikcerid]).gap_from_high = ((float)price - ((quoteongridhist)_istockearninghisthashtable[tikcerid]).high) / ((quoteongridhist)_istockearninghisthashtable[tikcerid]).close;
            //    ((quoteongrid)_istockearninghashtable[tikcerid]).gap_from_low = ((float)price - ((quoteongridhist)_istockearninghisthashtable[tikcerid]).low) / ((quoteongridhist)_istockearninghisthashtable[tikcerid]).close;
            //}
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you updating from another thread?

Comment: @AseemGautam Yes. I think so. How could I fix it? Now it is working. I let it run for few hours and it updates the data right. But i think here is still delay. I do not understand thread very well.

Answer (score 0):

Not only you need to have `PropertyChanged` event in a class, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's how the grid knows a class can inform of changes.